# Autocomplete only suggest files in the current folder

Tags: cmd

When using autocomplete, the shell will suggest the files in the current folder rather than the files that are in the folder I'm navigating to.

In the following example, it suggests files in "rmove-front" rather than in C:
[image: Suggests files in "rmove-front" rather than in C:]

How to fix this behavior ?

I apologize if the question has been answered already, I haven't found the page that treats this subject.

Thank you

Comment: That's a CMD prompt not PowerShell, you might want to change the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong slash, you need backslashes `..\..\` not forward slashes `../../`

Comment: I feel pretty dumb, thank you for the heads up.
Follow-up question, is there any way to use forward slashes as well ? I use forward slashes on my other windows machine, which is why I got confused.

Comment: CMD is a bit weird like that, possibly because of legacy support.  PowerShell is different as it converts `../../` to `'..\..\'` when you press tab and then cycle through the files in that path correctly.